# update Unix permissions on a windows share

Tags: powershell, unix, permissions

My Unix box has a mapping to a Windows share.  On the Windows server, a Powershell script is copying folders to this share UDI/inbound throughout the day.  On the Unix side where my Oracle database is running, I need to be able to update or write a file under one of these share folders.  But permissions are blocking me.  See visual below.

[image]

When looking at it from the Unix side, the owner/group(33448/32770) are different than my Unix login (orahubd/dba), so I cannot change the permissions from the Unix side.  Is there some way from the Windows side, like in my Powershell script, to change the permissions so that Unix would allow me to write?  I was able to set the permissions via Powershell to Everyone:Full, but that doesn't seem to change it from the Unix perspective.

I am an Oracle PL//SQL developer, just a novice dabbling in these other technologies.

Comment: You set the NTFS abd the Share pernissions on the Windows host? As a reminder, setting the share pernissions to everyone/full control basically means that pernissions are managed on filesystem level (so on an NTFS level)

Comment: @bluuf, yes in the Windows Powershell script that places the folder on the share, I was able to add some code that set permissions to everyone/full, but that still did not help from the Unix side.  It did not even show up as a change in the Unix permissions.

Comment: check the ntfs pernissions, on Windows the filesystem pernissions overrule the share pernissions.

Comment: You need to provide a lot more information than that. What are the mount options used for that share on the Unix side? What are the *share* permissions on the Windows side (e.g. [`Get-SharePermissions`](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/List-Share-Permissions-83f8c419))? What are the *filesystem* permissions on the Windows side (`Get-Acl`)?